# How to write console output from System.out to a file

Tags: java, networking, ssh, console, output

I have a device that I am connected to over SSH via Java that listens to console inputs and prints out values via System.out (this part of the set-up I cannot change).

I need to retrieve the plaintext output of the device and store it in a file. The data from the device is simple text sent to the System.out via SSH. Is there any way to get that data and save it to a file as it comes in? I cannot change the output stream due to the constraints of the device.

Comment: You can use `System.setOut` to set a custom PrintStream in place of System.out, which then might print to some sort of a buffer you have control over (or a pipe, using PipeOutputStream).

Comment: This is a little confusing.  You're connecting to a device over SSH, but worried about System.out.  Type of device?  SSH connection like a command line session, or a tunnel?  When it outputs to system.out is that on the "device" or on your computer your process is running from?

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply! Let me elaborate: it is a command line session. The device operates in a strange fashion that I cannot change because it is outside of my scope of work. Essentially, the device listens to whatever user (I) write to System.out onto the console, then parses that and having executed the task posts the output onto the console via System.out. I need to save that output into a file for later parsing.

The commands are passed to the device via a printStream that prints the commands to System.out and thus the console

Comment: The reason that I cannot change the System.out is due to the fact that the device in question parses commands directly out of the console, I have not been able to get it to respond in any other way. If I do not write commands to the console, the device will not be able to perform any tasks

Comment: You can still change System.out to something that writes the output to a file AND forwards the output to the original System.out.

Comment: What would I change the System.out to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to resolve the issue is to, prior to making the connection to the device, to change the System.out PrintStream to a FileOutputStream and then parse the log generated by this stream to get the data I need.